# cordova upload video while recording

Tags: node.js, cordova, sockets, file-upload, ionic-framework

I am using this org.apache.cordova.camera plugin for camera and media-capture for capturing videos.

I want to upload video to cloud/wowza while recording through camera (maybe using sockets). How to do this? Is there any plugin there to do this or how to achieve this?

Thanks for help

Comment: How should this be possible? What happens, if the user chooses to recapture his video or if he aborts the videocapture? I would suggest you to do the upload after the user has finished his recording with the file-transfer plugin for cordova.

Comment: Thanks @Sithys, Yes I can do using file transfer plugin but actually I want to stream the same file from cloud so for this I want to upload that at the time of recording.